# Solutions for binding JS objects for callbacks

Tags: javascript, typescript

I find that it's very common to have code like (this is TypeScript, but the equivalent JS is fairly obvious and this is really a JS problem, although one that TS could solve):

```
class Foo {
    someField;

    someMethod() {
        doSomethingTakingACallback(function() {
            this.someField; // Fails because `this` is not the instance of `Foo`
        });
    }
}
```

The solution, of course, is to use `Function.bind()` like so:

```
    someMethod() {
        doSomethingTakingACallback(function() {
            this.someField; // Works as expected
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

Now the problem is that I have callbacks that must access the object instance a lot (ie, I need to be calling `bind(this)` on many callbacks). I've now wasted more time on bugs resulting from this than I'd like to admit. Is there some alternative? Am I missing some easier way to do this? Is there any reason that this is the default behavior as opposed to the function that we get from calling `bind(this)`?

One solution I know of is to do something like `var me = this` and then call `me.someField` (etc). It's a little nicer looking when I have many callbacks or nested callbacks. Although then I lose out on the iconicness of `this`, which I feel makes it the most clear where the member is located (on the class that I'm writing).

Comment: A popular alternative to binding `this` to a function is to create a local variable referencing `this` (commonly named `self`) outside the function, and using that instead of `this`

Comment: Other popular names are `_this` and `that`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript and ES6/ES2015 both support the "fat arrow function" syntax, which allows you to use `this` the way you do in most other languages - to refer to the class instance object.

e.g.

```
    someMethod() {
         doSomethingTakingACallback(() => {
             this.someField;
         });
    }
```

This compiles to the following code:

```
 Foo.prototype.someMethod = function () {
     var _this = this;
     doSomethingTakingACallback(function () {
        _this.someField;
     });
 };
```

Comment: Both you and the8472 posted these similar answers around the same time, but I think the fact that this one mentions the ES5 equivalent makes it a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

ES6 [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) keep the `this` of the surrounding scope and thus do not need binding.

ES7 will (possibly) have the :: [bind operator](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind)

Comment: This seems to be the most ideal. I was aware of arrow functions, but not of the nature of `this` with them. Since I'm using TypeScript, there's already support for arrow functions, and I can't see any reason not to use them everywhere (they're certainly the anonymous function syntax that I'm more familiar with). I'm not actually sure why I wasn't already using arrow functions. I guess because I started with JS and had to support older browsers.

Comment: If you need to use the `arguments` variable, you can't use arrow functions. Or if you actually want to make use of the context (`this` value) that your function gets executed in (e.g. jQuery sets `this` to the DOM element in event handlers). Otherwise, I agree, arrow functions all the way.

Comment: @GregL: the `this` value obviously is not of interest to OP since he's already using `bind`. And many uses of `arguments` can be covered with the spread operator.

Answer (score 0):

Assign `this` to another variable outside of your callback method and use that.

```
class Foo {
    someField : any;

    someMethod() {

        var that = this;
        doSomethingTakingACallback(function () {
           // use that.someField; 
        });
    }
}
```